# NFC Tag reader can't be started in another class?

Tags: java, android, crash, nfc

I have written a program to read out nfc Tags and visualize them onto a Toast which works perfectly fine.
Code:

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    Tag myTag;
    Context context;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;





        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        readFromIntent(getIntent());

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected};
    }
    private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            }
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }
    }
    private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
//        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");

        try {
            // Get the Text
            text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }





    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        readFromIntent(intent);
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        }
    }

}
```

But when I want this to be started in another File the app just crashes without giving me an error.

This is my used code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Nfc nfc = new Nfc();
        nfc.startnfc();

    }
}
```

I didn't change the onCreate since it was imported from my main app, so you have an easier time to understand my code. It obviously wouldn't make a difference..

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import static java.sql.DriverManager.println;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Nfc extends Activity {

    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    Tag myTag;
    Context context;


        public void startnfc() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;





        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        readFromIntent(getIntent());

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected};
    }
    private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            }
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }
    }
    private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
//        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");

        try {
            // Get the Text
            text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }





    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        readFromIntent(intent);
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        }
    }

}
```

this is my second week Ive been programming with Java. Sorry in advance for dumb mistakes

Comment: I'm not savvy in the ways of Android, but I don't think that you should be calling `onCreate()` that way, that you need a Bundle passed into it, but having said this, your question looks to be a possible [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. I think that the NFC tag reading code probably should be in its own class, and that you use it in whichever activity you need it in, but don't create new Activity objects in this way or for this purpose.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels but it works in the first case. The onCreate() in code #2 / #3  is just a regular function it could also be called startnfc etc.

Comment: Also, regarding, *"But when I want this to be started in another File the app just crashes without giving me an error."* -- Are you sure? Have you checked the LogCat? If so, what does it show?

Comment: Regarding, *"but it works in the first case...."* -- but you're creating your Activity in the second code in a non-standard and unusual way, and this just doesn't look "kosher" to me. But again, I am most definitely ***not*** an Android expert, and in fact, we'd best tag your question with the [tag:android] tag to make sure that the right experts *see* your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes logcat has no output

Comment: So, *again* you're creating an Activity in a non-standard way, without passing in a proper Bundle, without calling `super.onCreate(properBundle)`, again, I fear that you're setting yourself up for failure in this way. Again, I predict that the NVC tag reading code should be in its own class *outside* of the Activity class, and then used by the Activity class. Don't keep trying to create bad Activities. Again, let's see if an Android expert can chime in here.

Comment: 1) When your logcat es empty, try to reboot it.
2) Also, you can plug Firebase Crashlytics and then you will see not only your crashes from Firebase console, also you can see ceashes your app's users.
3) My Xiaomi smartphone after 3 crashes displaying order about error and I can see exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard class inheritance problem.

Really what it looks like you were trying to do create a new base class by extending `Activity`

So in your `MainActivity.java` change the line

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {`

to

`public class MainActivity extends Nfc {`

then you can change

```
Nfc nfc = new Nfc();
nfc.startnfc();
```

to

`startnfc()`

As your `Nfc` class has already extended the `Activity` class, so when the Android framework creates an instance of `MainActivity` your `startnfc` method is available

The `Activity` or something extended from that is not something you ever create an instance of yourself